Partition mysql table on varchar column
I Have a mysql(v8.x) table with 4 Billion records and I need to partition on one of the varchar column.
Partition on date column or integer column doesn't work in this case.
This is a unique usecase.
Partitioning will be on cust_id column
cust_id contains data like below
| 2184-204CECE8FPNE_01_0102_4 |
| 2184-08NFINO3NC0E_01_0102_4 |
| 2185-B28RNFPE3NCS_01_0102_4 |
| 2185-HP3DNFNF2DNF_01_0102_4 |
| 9732-0I02NCNN30DW_01_0102_4 |
| 9732-8JFN30FJMDP3_01_0102_4 |
| 9732-B02F30CN3D25_01_0102_4 |
| 3184-N33NF4FNPF33_01_0102_4 |
| 3184-0702NDNDJD3S_01_0102_4 |

since we have hyphen in the data, how would I partition the data?
Yes, partition will be on first set of digits(before the character hyphen - before the First hyphen only)
I was trying to create a table as below snippet, i failed with it :(
Appreciate all the help,
Thank you
Here is the create statement I tried with, it didn't work
CREATE TABLE cust_part (
  id varchar(127) NOT NULL,
  cust_id varchar(127) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id,cust_id),
  KEY idx_cust_id (cust_id)
) 
PARTITION BY RANGE COLUMNS (substring_index(cust_id,'-',1))
(
PARTITION p1000 VALUES LESS THAN ('1000'),
PARTITION p2000 VALUES LESS THAN ('2000'),
PARTITION p3000 VALUES LESS THAN ('3000'),
PARTITION p4000 VALUES LESS THAN ('4000'),
PARTITION p5000 VALUES LESS THAN ('5000'),
PARTITION p6000 VALUES LESS THAN ('6000'),
PARTITION p7000 VALUES LESS THAN ('7000'),
PARTITION p8000 VALUES LESS THAN ('8000'),
PARTITION p9000 VALUES LESS THAN ('9000'),
PARTITION p10000 VALUES LESS THAN ('10000'),
PARTITION pMax VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
);


The presence of p10000 and pMax at the same time allows to assert that the prefix may contain more than 4 digits.. is this true? if so then normalize all prefixes to some constant length (for example, 5 digits) and adjust the length using zerofill - this will allow to use RANGE (not RANGE COLUMNS) partitioning by the used expression.

What query will benefit from such partitioning?  Bill's solution will probably provide no performance benefit for any query.

@RickJames I tested with EXPLAIN, and a query that searched for a specific cust_id does benefit from partition pruning.

@BillKarwin - What query did you have?

@RickJames, explain select * from cust_part where cust_id = '1500-xyz'; shows partitions: p2000 which shows it is pruning to a single partition.

@BillKarwin - That does not make it any faster than using the index.  Or, especially if the PK starts with cust_id, as per my Answer.

@RickJames Well, the question was about partitioning, not about performance. :-)

Bobby -- What is the goal of partitioning?  Performance?  Or something else?

This table is almost a TB size with 3.5Billion records in it. cust_id is varchar(127) column. Yes, performance is the main reason. I do have an index on cust_id column, still performance is very bad. 256GB ram allocated to the instance. Am trying to setup a partition on cust_id column for any performance gains. This test going against cloned RDS instance, Changes will be applied to live DB once we are satisfied with the performance results.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/partitioning-columns-range.html says:


RANGE COLUMNS does not accept expressions, only names of columns.


So you can't use substring_index() or any other function.
You don't have to. You can rely on strings being ordered less than or greater than the fixed values you use in the partition defs.
But you must keep in mind that because the column is a varchar, not an integer, you must order the ranges in alphabetical order, not numeric order.
The following works:
CREATE TABLE cust_part (
  id varchar(127) NOT NULL,
  cust_id varchar(127) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id,cust_id),
  KEY idx_cust_id (cust_id)
) 
PARTITION BY RANGE COLUMNS (cust_id)
(
PARTITION p1000 VALUES LESS THAN ('1000-'),
PARTITION p10000 VALUES LESS THAN ('10000-'),
PARTITION p2000 VALUES LESS THAN ('2000-'),
PARTITION p3000 VALUES LESS THAN ('3000-'),
PARTITION p4000 VALUES LESS THAN ('4000-'),
PARTITION p5000 VALUES LESS THAN ('5000-'),
PARTITION p6000 VALUES LESS THAN ('6000-'),
PARTITION p7000 VALUES LESS THAN ('7000-'),
PARTITION p8000 VALUES LESS THAN ('8000-'),
PARTITION p9000 VALUES LESS THAN ('9000-'),
PARTITION pMax VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
);

Alphabetically, '10000-' goes between '1000-' and '2000-'. You'll have to order any further partitions in a similar way.

https://dbfiddle.uk/oe0nC9mg

Thank you, will implement as suggested

Give this a try...
CREATE TABLE cust_part (
  id varchar(127) NOT NULL,   -- How is this generated??
  cust_id varchar(127) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (cust_id, id),  -- Note the order
  KEY idx_cust_id (id)
)                             -- No partitioning

If there are many rows for the typical cust_id, this will help due to "locality of reference" ("clustering").

ID = cust_ID+sequential_auto_generated_value ... like below
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID                                           |  Cust_id
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
11-XXXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-2-100 |  11-XXXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-2
10-XXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX222222-101         |  10-XXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX222   

yes, every cust_id will have a multiple rows (Spread over years - last 20 years)

do you think "PARTITION BY KEY(cust_id) partitions 50" helps ??? for better performance?

No that is no better than having cust_id at the start of an index.
